# HOw to fix CAps LOck DElay

Tags: keyboard, performance

[December 28, 2018]

I've been experiencing delays using the caps lock key. As you can see in the title, uppercase letters appear consecutively (CAps) even though I pressed the caps lock key (C - caps lock  - A) before I press another letter.  In order to achieve proper capitalization I need to stop typing for a second whenever I press the caps lock which messes with my typing rhythm. The slow keys is off in Universal Access. This problem doesn't exist in Windows. I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to give it a chance but this problem is bugging me for a while now. Any help regarding this matter will be greatly appreciated. The version of my Ubuntu is **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS**.

To illustrate the problem (pressing caps lock alternately):

Windows - AaAaAaAa

Ubuntu - AAAAAAAA

---

[December 29, 2018]

Is there any other way to fix this problem rather than switching to Shift key. I'm used to caps lock key and I have a good reason why I can't just switch to Shift. I also tried using different keyboards, 2 local brand and 2 international brand (I have 3 spare keyboards = 4 keyboards in total) and the problem is still present. If there is no other fix to this problem then I have no choice but to replace Caps lock with Shift which is disappointing and will cause delay to my workflow.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Nice title!

Comment: Tested on my 16.04 LTS and caps lock key works faster than me. IOW OP's problem does not occur here.